JPA @GeneratedValue - Don't always want a generated Value
In a Spring Boot JPA application, I have a table where we will use a sequence to generate values. However, we also need to insert entries into the table that already have their values generated. (These values will also use the sequence to generate the IDs to prevent duplicates, but this will happen earlier in the workflow.)
For example, the savedFoo in the code below will not have the same ID as the Foo entity I created manually using the constructor.
However, I will also have a case where I don't already have an ID generated, and I will need the sequence generator to generate one for me.
Is it possible to use @GeneratedValue in this way?
Foo foo = new Foo(123);
Foo savedFoo = fooJpaRepository.save(foo);

Example entity class
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
public class Foo {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "foo_fooid_gen")
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "foo_fooid_gen", sequenceName = "foo_fooid_seq", allocationSize = 1)
  @Column(name = "foo_id", nullable = false)
  private int id;

  public Foo(int id) {
    this.id = id
  }

}


You need to change the type of id to Integer. Set it to null and Hibernate will fill it for you.
TBH, your constructor is pointless. You shouldn't set id manually while using generator.

Unfortunately, we must keep the ID for data integrity in this case. This is why I'm asking if we can prevent Hibernate from changing the ID we set.

Did you tried to remove @GeneratedValue annotation? You can either let Hibernate manage your ids or do it yourself. Not both.

And if you have some external id you need to store, just store it in separate field.
